# working with a pointer to a buffer filled with utf 16 plain text

Tags: c++, pointers, utf-16

got some problem while working on a c++ project.
i got a function from a framework which fills a "memory buffer with either null-terminated UTF-16 plain text or null-terminated ASCII HTML code, and returns a pointer to it"(info from documentation).

i am not so familiar with the pointer topic so i tried to do something like this:

```
WCHAR* pointerToMetaData[1024] = (WCHAR[]*) XWF_GetMetadataEx(hItem, 0);
currentFile.metaData = *pointerToMetaData;
```

i know that the return value is a LPVOID so i have to convert the return value to the correct datatype...but sadly this works not quite qell...

maybe some more confident user could help me solving this problem?!

Comment: The return value from `XWF_GetMetadataEx` is `LPVOID`? Is it null terminated? If so, you can copy the string into `pointerToMetaData` with [`wcsncpy, wcsncpy_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcsncpy). However, there are other issues....

Comment: You probbaly want this: `WCHAR MetaData[1024]; wcsncpy(MetaData, (WCHAR*)XWF_GetMetadataEx(hItem, 0), 1024);` but it's hard to tell without more information. Also the specification _"...UTF-16 plain text or null-terminated ASCII HTML code"_ is very strange but at least unclear. You need to grasp at least the basics of pointers, otherwise you'll have a hard time modifying this piece of software.

Comment: `WCHAR* pointerToMetaData[1024] = (WCHAR[]*) XWF_GetMetadataEx(hItem, 0);` That line seems incorrect. LPVOID is not an array of pointers. `WCHAR* pointerToMetaData[1024]` Is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`XWF_GetMetadataEx()` returns an `LPVOID` (aka `void*`) because it can return one of two different data formats: UTF-16 plain text (handled with `wchar_t*`) or ASCII HTML (handled with `char*`).  Per the [documentation](https://www.x-ways.net/forensics/x-tensions/XWF_functions.html) for `XWF_GetMetadataEx()`:

> ```c
> LPVOID XWF_GetMetadataEx(
>   HANDLE hItem,
>   PDWORD lpnFlags
> );
> ```
>
> Available in v18.9 and later. Can extract extensive internal metadata of files of various types, exactly as seen in Details mode in X-Ways Forensics, typically much more than GetMetadata. Fills a memory buffer with either null-terminated UTF-16 plain text or null-terminated ASCII HTML code, and returns a pointer to it. You may parse the buffer to retrieve specific metadata that you need. The format may theoretically change from one version to the other. You must release the allocated memory by passing that pointer to XWF_ReleaseMem when you do not need it any more. If no metadata is extracted, the return value is NULL instead.
>
> Unlike XWF_GetMetadata, this function is thread-safe. Unlike XWF_GetExtractedMetadata, the file must have been opened with XWF_OpenItem because this function reads from the file contents, not from data stored in the volume snapshot. The metadata is taken from the very file that contains it, for example in the case of zip-style Office documents from the XML files.
>
> **`lpnFlags` points to flags for input and output. The only currently defined input flag is 0x01. It tells X-Ways Forensics to extract only a subset of the available metadata, as shown in the software in the Metadata column. The resulting buffer currently contains always UTF-16 plain text. If the flag is not set, the complete metadata as seen in Details mode is extracted. The resulting buffer can be of either above-mentioned formats.**
>
> **The only currently defined output flag is 0x01 (indicating, if set, that the resulting buffer is HTML-formatted ASCII instead of UTF-16 plain text). If any of the 8 highest bits are set, you should not touch the resulting buffer, just release it with XWF_ReleaseMem. The output flags are valid only if the function was successful, i.e. if it has returned a pointer.**

So, you need to either:

1. explicitly request the desired output format and cast to that specific type:

   ```cpp
   DWORD flags = 1; // <-- want UTF-16 only
   wchar_t *Utf16PlainTextMetaData = (wchar_t*) XWF_GetMetadataEx(hItem, &flags);
   if (Utf16PlainTextMetaData)
   {
       if ((flags & 0xFF000000) == 0) // is the buffer usable?
       {
           // use Utf16PlainTextMetaData as needed...
       }

       XWF_ReleaseMem(Utf16PlainTextMetaData);
   }
   ```
2. detect which format is being output and then cast accordingly:

   ```cpp
   DWORD flags = 0; // <-- want either format
   LPVOID pointerToMetaData = XWF_GetMetadataEx(hItem, &flags);
   if (pointerToMetaData)
   {
       if ((flags & 0xFF000000) == 0) // is the buffer usable?
       {
           if (flags & 1)
           {
               char *HtmlAsciiMetaData = (char*) pointerToMetaData;
               // use HtmlAsciiMetaData as needed...
           }
           else
           {
               wchar_t *Utf16PlainTextMetaData = (wchar_t*) pointerToMetaData;
               // use Utf16PlainTextMetaData as needed...
           }
       }

       XWF_ReleaseMem(pointerToMetaData);
   }
   ```